# UEFI Add Boot Option programmatically

Tags: uefi

How can i write code which add boot option from UEFI driver programmatically?
1) I try to add "Boot0001" variable:

```
  ZeroMem(Data, 2048);
  StrCpy(Data, L"Boot0001");
  DataSize = StrLen(Data) * 2;

  Status = gRT->SetVariable(L"Boot0001", &dGuid, Attr, DataSize, &Data);
```

2) I need add entry to "BootOrder" variable. But i can't understand how.
Ideally, i want to add boot option boot from sample efi application.

Comment: 1) What is the result?
2) What aspect do you not understand?

Comment: 1) new variable "Boot0001" in NVRAM. 2) How to change "BootOrder" variable to add "Boot0001" option as second option?

Comment: (Sorry, out travelling, intermittent computer access.) OK that makes it clear enough to answer.

Answer (score 2):

To add something to UEFI boot list:

1. Create BootXXXX variable, it's format looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0z2K.png).
2. Change BootOrder variable, adding newly created option somewhere in the list.

You can find a working code snippet [in UEFI shell sources](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/ShellPkg/Library/UefiShellBcfgCommandLib/UefiShellBcfgCommandLib.c#L526).

Answer (score 1):

How this works is described in the UEFI specification - available without payment from [the UEFI Forum](http://uefi.org/specifications). The current version is 2.4B.

The BootOrder variable mechanism (among other things) is described in section 3.2 - Globally Defined Variables, but I'll give a brief summary.

It is an array of **UINT16** elements in the order of the preferred boot order. The **UINT16** value is the number portion of your `Boot####` variable name. So to rank options `Boot0001`, `Boot0002` and `Boot0003` in reverse order of preference, your BootOrder variable should contain (hex, ignoring endianness) `000300020001`.

It also needs to have Non-Volatile, Boot-services and Runtime-services attributes set (as described in table 11 in that chapter).