# Default UEFI boot order (in the firmware image)

Tags: firmware, uefi

Building a firmware using EDK2, what is the easiest way to provide a custom default boot order?

For instance, I know that Ovmf for QEMU redefines programmatically the UEFI boot order based on QEMU's "bootorder" fw_cfg file (using code in QemuBootOrderLib).
So, similarly, I could specify and enforce a boot order programmatically.

Is there a simpler way to achieve that (perhaps providing custom values for UEFI vars)?

Note: without using the shell! I need this configuration included in the firmware image!

Comment: Might be better to ask on http://SuperUser.com?

Comment: mmmh why do you think that? The topic is firmware development! :)

Comment: Subject edited for clarity!

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide Boot0001/Boot0002/... and BootOrder variables. The first have specified format and require a valid device paths to work properly, so your boot devices should also be predefined, the second is just a list of UINT16s. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525590/uefi-add-boot-option-programmatically/26561930#26561930) for more info.

Comment: Thanks but that would be the programmatic way to do it (for instance a similar thing is done by qemu).

Comment: In other words, is there a way to provide default values for variables in the firmware binary?

Comment: As far as I know, NVRAM content (including default values for variables) is fully implementation dependent. You need to study OvmfPkg source code to see how (or if ever) are the defaults stored there.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from OS shell too, there is a utility called `virt-fw-vars` which is distributed in `python3-virt-firmware` on Red Hat systems. To create "one shot" reboot with HTTP UEFI URL do this:

```
virt-fw-vars -i /usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS.fd --set-boot-uri http://myserver/boot/shim.efi -o mydomain_VARS.fd
```

To change boot order permanently, you can use the same tool to manipulate `Boot####` variables, see the help screen for more info. NVRAM image files typically reside in `/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram` so these files you want to modify. Here is an output of a VM of mine:

```
# virt-fw-vars -i /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/bohemia_VARS.fd -p
INFO: reading raw edk2 varstore from /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/bohemia_VARS.fd
INFO: var store range: 0x64 -> 0xe000
5254007EE2ED        : blob: 60 bytes
Attempt 1           : blob: 1049 bytes
Attempt 2           : blob: 1049 bytes
Attempt 3           : blob: 1049 bytes
Attempt 4           : blob: 1049 bytes
Attempt 5           : blob: 1049 bytes
Attempt 6           : blob: 1049 bytes
Attempt 7           : blob: 1049 bytes
Attempt 8           : blob: 1049 bytes
Boot0000            : boot entry: title="UiApp" devpath=FvName(7cb8bdc9-f8eb-4f34-aaea-3ee4af6516a1)/FvFileName(462caa21-7614-4503-836e-8ab6f4662331)
Boot0001            : boot entry: title="UEFI Misc Device" devpath=PciRoot()/PCI(dev=07:0) optdata=4eac0881119f594d850ee21a522c59b2
Boot0002            : boot entry: title="EFI Internal Shell" devpath=FvName(7cb8bdc9-f8eb-4f34-aaea-3ee4af6516a1)/FvFileName(7c04a583-9e3e-4f1c-ad65-e05268d0b4d1)
Boot0007            : boot entry: title="Red Hat 6" devpath=PciRoot()/PCI(dev=07:0)/Partition(nr=1)/FilePath(\EFI\redhat\grub.efi)
BootOrder           : boot order: 0007, 0001, 0002, 0000
ClientId            : blob: 20 bytes
ConIn               : devpath: PciRoot()/PCI(dev=01:0)/ACPI(hid=0x30341d0,uid=0x0)
ConOut              : devpath: PciRoot()/PCI(dev=01:0)/ACPI(hid=0x50141d0,uid=0x0)/Msg(subtype=0xe)/Msg(subtype=0xa)
ErrOut              : devpath: PciRoot()/PCI(dev=01:0)/ACPI(hid=0x50141d0,uid=0x0)/Msg(subtype=0xe)/Msg(subtype=0xa)
InitialAttemptOrder : qword: 0x0807060504030201
Key0000             : blob: 14 bytes
Key0001             : blob: 14 bytes
Lang                : ascii: "eng"
MTC                 : dword: 0x00000017
MemoryTypeInformation: blob: 48 bytes
PlatformLang        : ascii: "en"
Timeout             : word: 0x0000
VarErrorFlag        : byte: 0xff
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UINT16 BootOrder[] = { 0x0001, 0x0002, 0x0000 }; // Change this array to your desired boot order
gRT->SetVariable(
   L"BootOrder",
   &gEfiGlobalVariableGuid,
   EFI_VARIABLE_BOOTSERVICE_ACCESS | EFI_VARIABLE_RUNTIME_ACCESS,
   sizeof(BootOrder),
   BootOrder
);
```

Comment: Where should I change it? The numbers does not give much in informations on what it going to be booted

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of struggling on this, I ended up sending a MR to edk2 project https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/pull/5126

It add a pcd `gEfiMdeModulePkgTokenSpaceGuid.PcdPlatformBootBoot0000` that can be set on the build command line.
For example adding `--pcd=gEfiMdeModulePkgTokenSpaceGuid.PcdPlatformBootBoot0000=Lshell.efi`
on the command line will make the first boot entry to be the UEFI shell.